# Why is this list changing value?

Tags: python, list

I have a `list` called `ones` that changes value after a block of code that shouldn't affect it. Why?

```
s = 3

ones = []
terms = []
for i in range (0, s):
    ones.append(1)
terms.append(ones)
print(terms)

twos = []
if len(ones) > 1:
    twos.append(ones)
    twos[-1].pop()
    twos[-1][-1] = 2
    print(twos)

print(terms)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1]]  # terms
[[1, 1, 2]]  # twos
[1, 1, 2]    # terms
```

For context, I'm trying to use this to begin to solve the problem on page 5 of this British Informatics Olympiad past exam: http://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2009/bio/bio09-exam.pdf.

Comment: Both `terms.append(ones)` and `twos.append(ones)` append references to the list held in `ones`, `twos[-1][-1] = 2` mutates that list.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: @khelwood Thank you for the reply. `terms` contains `ones` once, as far as I can see. What am I missing?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by references. I thought that `twos.append(ones)` simply added the content of `ones` onto the end of `twos`. Is that wrong?

Comment: It is wrong. For that you'd use [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: It seems, you use Python 2. I recommend to use Python 3, if you just started.

Comment: @Piinthesky Good shout! I'm downloading it now. Apart from print, xrange and integer division, are there any key differences I should know about (every article I can see looks very long!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
twos.append(ones)
```

You are appending a **reference** to `ones`, not its values. See the difference:

```
In [1]: l1 = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: l2 = []

In [3]: l2.append(l1)

In [4]: l2, l1
Out[4]: ([[1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3])

In [5]: l2[0][1] = 'test'

In [6]: l2, l1
Out[6]: ([[1, 'test', 3]], [1, 'test', 3])
```

In order to avoid this you can give a copy by using `[:]` operator:

```
In [7]: l1 = [1, 2, 3]

In [8]: l2 = []

In [9]: l2.append(l1[:])

In [10]: l2, l1
Out[10]: ([[1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3])

In [11]: l2[0][1] = 'test'

In [12]: l2, l1
Out[12]: ([[1, 'test', 3]], [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

`twos.append(ones)` does not copy `ones`.

There is only ever one list `ones` in memory, which also goes by the following references:

1. `terms[0]`
2. `twos[0]`

and also `terms[-1]` and `twos[-1]` because `terms` and `twos` only have one element each, so the first is the last.

Now, when you *mutate* `ones`/`terms[0]`/`terms[-1]`/`twos[0]`/`twos[-1]` you are mutating the same list in memory.

I highly recommend watching [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).

Comment: I can't upvote you yet, but thank you - and I will watch the video.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `twos.append(ones)`, you're passing the reference to the ones list, not the value itself. Therefore, when you do `twos[-1][-1] = 2`, it'll modify the value in the ones list itself, not a copy in the twos list.

To pass the value instead of the reference to the ones list, you can do:

```
twos.append(ones[:])
```

Comment: Ah right, thank you. Now how do I pass on the value of `ones` rather than a reference?

Comment: Try doing `twos = ones[:]`

Comment: Thank you! I tried `twos.append(ones[:])` and that seemed to work.